# OS X - 'Clickable' script to erase files?

Tags: macos, script, click

I use Latex to write my documents. Latex creates MANY auxiliary files to compile a document. I often times want to clean my working directory.

When I was working on Windows, I used to keep a .bat file in the working directory that looked like this:

```
del *.aux
del *.pdf
del *.log
del *.bak
del *.gz
del *.bbl
del *.blg
```

which I could just click on to get rid of all auxiliary files.

Now, I want to do the same on my Mac. I have created a .sh file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd `pwd`

echo "Cleaning files..."

rm *.aux
rm *.bak
rm *.bbl
rm *.blg
rm *.gz
rm *.log
rm *.pdf

echo "Done!"
```

which I know I can run (i.e. invoke from command line), but I cannot click on - which is more convenient because not always I will be using Terminal.

How can I convert this script into a "clickable" one?

I appreciate any input!

Comment: `chmod +x myfile.sh` now you should. You can also assign an icon using the get info menu so it will look nice :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I click on the file, the program invoked still is textedit.

Comment: you may need to go to Get Info, and change the default program there

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. However, the `rm` commands were not applied in the current directory. I guess they were executed in the home dir. Luckily, I did not have any file that matches the to be deleted file extensions. Any sugestions on the script to run on the directory it was invoked from?

Comment: add this code: `cd "pwd"` but replace the " with backticks

Comment: Still no good. I've updated the code I'm using on the original post. I guess it's hard for the terminal to "detect" the directory the click came from...

Comment: perhaps instead use: `cd $(dirname $0)`. Something like http://pastebin.com/eQR3GG6N

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25555/discussion-between-thiagoveloso-and-vihan1086).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" || {
    echo "Error changing directory." >&2
    exit 1
}

echo "Cleaning files..."

rm *.aux
rm *.bak
rm *.bbl
rm *.blg
rm *.gz
rm *.log
rm *.pdf

echo "Done!"
```

Give it a ".command" extension, and add execute permission to it. This will make it automatically open and run in Terminal when it's double-clicked.

Note that there are two important differences (and one minor one) between this and @thiagoveloso's script:

- It uses double-quotes around the path it's `cd`ing to, which will prevent problems if any directory names contain spaces (which is entirely normal on OS X).
- It checks for errors while `cd`ing, and if there was a problem it exits (rather than deleting files in an unexpected location). *Always* check for errors on any script command that affects what the rest of the script will do; `cd` is a good example of this.
- (Minor) It `cd`s directly to the script's directory (rather than `cd`ing there, capturing that location in a variable, then `cd`ing there *again* based on the variable).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The error checking contribution was definitely a nice improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Based on this reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in), I ended up solving my problem with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

echo "Cleaning files..."

cd $DIR
rm *.aux
rm *.bak
rm *.bbl
rm *.blg
rm *.gz
rm *.log
rm *.pdf

echo "Done!"

#read -p "Press [Enter] to continue..."
```

It works very well to clean all the nasty files left behind by Texmaker!